# Unable to login in Ubuntu 12.04 after update

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I face a login loop and I am unable to login.

I tried reinstalling lightdm, ubuntu-desktop, but doesnt help.
I installed gdm and used it as my default for a while to see if it was a lightdm issue.

But here it seems like that there are 3 incorrect password attempts on something that starts when I login. I think my sudoers file is correct.

Here is my auth.log -

```
May 23 14:52:01 ubuntu-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user lightdm
May 23 14:52:02 ubuntu-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user angad by (uid=0)
May 23 14:52:02 ubuntu-desktop lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
May 23 14:52:02 ubuntu-desktop sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
May 23 14:52:02 ubuntu-desktop sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [angad]
May 23 14:52:02 ubuntu-desktop sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
May 23 14:52:02 ubuntu-desktop sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [angad]
May 23 14:52:02 ubuntu-desktop sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
May 23 14:52:02 ubuntu-desktop sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [angad]
May 23 14:52:02 ubuntu-desktop sudo:    angad : 3 incorrect password attempts ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/angad ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
May 23 14:52:05 ubuntu-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user angad
May 23 14:52:06 ubuntu-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
May 23 14:52:06 ubuntu-desktop lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
May 23 14:52:07 ubuntu-desktop lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "angad"
May 23 14:52:07 ubuntu-desktop dbus[936]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.166" (uid=104 pid=7935 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.17" (uid=0 pid=1426 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
```

Comment: What if you boot to a different runlevel? Also, try disabling services in init.d. See [Starting services at boot in Linux](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/11/04/starting-services-at-boot-in-linux/)

Comment: Give more information on what you mean with "a login loop". Do you enter tha password, press Enter, and then just get prompted to enter it again, or what do you mean?